# How to use Oracle connection in SSIS?

Tags: oracle, ssis, oledb, oracle12c

I must develop a SSIS Package with Oracle connection. I'm using Windows 8.1 64bit with Visual Studio 2010 and Oracle version 12c(remotely).

I would use "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" like picture:
[image]

Where I insert my connection parameters:
[image]

After "TEST CONNECTION" command I get this error:
[image]

**[UPDATE]**

After installation of ODTA 32bit I can test my connection, but when I try preview result of Data Source component, I get this error:
[image]

**[UPDATE-SOLUTION]**
I've resolved this problem setting this parameter equal true:
[image]

Why I get this error? How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: We found the MS driver for Oracle to be slower compared to the one provided by Oracle.  If you have it installed, just scroll down, and choose "Oracle provider for OLEDB"

Comment: Hi Raj, thanks for your hint. I have not this driver installer. I would not execute hard operation, my priority is make working my package. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [32-bit ODAC 12c for Windows x86](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html).

Comment: Hi Stefan, I've installed ODAC 12c for Windows x64 but I have the same error.

Comment: Ok try to install the 32 bit version. I think Visual Studio is a 32 bit app.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I've added new details about this problem. After your hint I can test my connection with success but I can't preview data from Data Source component.